# Equivalent irreducible representations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

suppose you have two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ acting on a space $H$.
Suppose $H=\bigoplus_{i}E_{i}$ and $G_1$, $G_2$ acting irreducibly on any $E_{i}$.

Can I deduce that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are just two equivalent representation of the same group?

Thanks!

Fabio

Answer (score 1):

No, take $H$ to be $k$ a field, there are a lot of non trivial action of groups on $k$ which are not isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused because I found that irreducible representations are unique up to unitary transformations and in my case both groups acts irreducibly on the  SAME subspaces $E_i$ of the decomposition.